# Cannibals and missionaries problem python -artificial intelligence algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to solve the [cannibals and missionaries problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missionaries_and_cannibals_problem) in python (with some additional criteria, but the main idea is the classic one).

So, in the class `Graph`, I initialize the state (number of cannibals, number of missionaries, available seats in the boat, units of food (missionaries can feed cannibals if there are more cannibals than missionaries), etc.

Then I have the method `genereazaSuccesori` which is not working how is supposed to because I'm doing something wrong, I don't know what. So this method should generate successors for a node (parameter `nodCurent`).

From what I saw while I was debugging in Pycharm, the main issue is that my program somehow exits before it executes the third for (where I append in `listaSuccesori`, so the array returned is empty.

Does anyone know what I did wrong with my code? Especially why my code doesn't execute the third for?

Even a link with a full example of this problem implemented in python would help me (but the one where there is food as well because things get messier here, the basic one is pretty easy).

Thanks!

**`solver.py`:**

```
import math


class NodParcurgere:
    def __init__(self, info, parinte):
        self.info = info
        self.parinte = parinte  # parintele din arborele de parcurgere

    def obtineDrum(self):
        l = [self];
        nod = self
        while nod.parinte is not None:
            l.insert(0, nod.parinte)
            nod = nod.parinte
        return l

    def afisDrum(self):  # returneaza si lungimea drumului
        l = self.obtineDrum()
        for nod in l:
            print(str(nod))
        return len(l)

    def contineInDrum(self, infoNodNou):
        nodDrum = self
        while nodDrum is not None:
            if (infoNodNou == nodDrum.info):
                return True
            nodDrum = nodDrum.parinte

        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        sir = ""
        sir += str(self.info) + "\n"
        return (sir)

    def __str__(self):
        sir = ""
        sir += str(self.info) + "\n"
        return (sir)


class Graph:  # graful problemei
    def __init__(self, numeFisier):
        f = open(numeFisier, "r")
        textFisier = f.read()
        infoFisier = textFisier.split("\n")
        for i in infoFisier:
            date_citite = i.split("=");
            print(date_citite);
            if date_citite[0] == "N1":
                Graph.N1 = int(date_citite[1]);  # N1 canibali,
            if date_citite[0] == "N2":
                Graph.N2 = int(date_citite[1]);  # N2 misionari
            if date_citite[0] == "Nr":
                Graph.Nr = int(date_citite[
                    1]);  # La fiecare Nr deplasari cu barca (de la un mal la celalalt) un loc din barca se va degrada
            if date_citite[0] == "MalInitial":
                Graph.MalInitial = date_citite[1];
            if date_citite[0] == "MalFinal":
                Graph.MalFinal = date_citite[1];
            if date_citite[0] == "M":
                Graph.M = int(date_citite[1]);
        f.close();
        canibali_mal_opus = 0
        misionari_mal_opus = 0
        pozitie_barca_mal_opus = 0
        pozitie_barca_mal_initial = 1
        nr_unitati_hrana_opus = 0
        nr_unitati_hrana_initial = 0
        numar_deplasari = 0;
        f = open(numeFisier, "r")
        textFisier = f.read()
        infoFisier = textFisier.split("\n")
        for i in infoFisier:
            date_citite = i.split("=");
            #print(date_citite);
            if date_citite[0] == "K":
                nr_unitati_hrana_initial = int(date_citite[1])
        self.start = (
            Graph.N1, Graph.N2, canibali_mal_opus, misionari_mal_opus, pozitie_barca_mal_initial,
            nr_unitati_hrana_initial,
            nr_unitati_hrana_opus, numar_deplasari);

        # TODO care e starea finala buna?
        self.scopuri = [(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
        #print("stare initiala", self.start);

        # nr canibali pe mal initial si pe mal opus
        # nr misionari mal initial si mai opus

    def genereazaSuccesori(self, nodCurent):

        def test_conditie(mis, can):
            return mis == 0 or mis >= can

        listaSuccesori = []
        barca = nodCurent.info[4]
        if barca == 1:
            canMalCurent = nodCurent.info[0]
            misMalCurent = nodCurent.info[1]
            canMalOpus = int(Graph.N1) - int(canMalCurent)
            misMalOpus = int(Graph.N2) - int(misMalCurent)
            hranaMalCurent = nodCurent.info[5]
            hranaMalOpus = nodCurent.info[6]
        else:
            canMalOpus = nodCurent.info[0]
            misMalOpus = nodCurent.info[1]
            canMalCurent = Graph.N1 - canMalOpus
            misMalCurent = Graph.N2 - misMalOpus
            hranaMalCurent = nodCurent.info[6]
            hranaMalOpus = nodCurent.info[5]
        maxMisionariBarca = min(int(Graph.M - nodCurent.info[7] % 3), misMalCurent)
        for misBarca in range(0,maxMisionariBarca + 1):
            if misBarca == 0:
                maxCanibaliBarca = min(Graph.M - nodCurent.info[7] % Graph.Nr, canMalCurent)
                minCanibaliBarca = 1  # pt ca barca nu merge singura
            else:
                maxCanibaliBarca = min(Graph.M - nodCurent.info[7] % 3 - misBarca, canMalCurent,
                                       misBarca + nodCurent.info[5] * 2)
                minCanibaliBarca = 0

            for canBarca in range(minCanibaliBarca, maxCanibaliBarca + 1):
                minHrana = math.ceil(nodCurent.info[0] - nodCurent.info[1] / 2)
                maxHrana = min(nodCurent.info[5], Graph.M - misBarca - canBarca)
                for hrana in range(minHrana, maxHrana):
                    hranaBarca = hrana;
                    canMalCurentNou = canMalCurent - canBarca
                    misMalCurentNou = misMalCurent - misBarca
                    canMalOpusNou = canMalOpus + canBarca
                    misMalOpusNou = misMalOpus + misBarca
                    nodCurent_list = list(nodCurent.info);
                    nodCurent_list[7] = nodCurent_list[7]+1;
                    nodCurent.info = tuple(nodCurent_list)
                    hranaNou = hranaMalCurent - hranaBarca;
                    hranaOpus=0;
                    if(canBarca > misBarca):
                        hranaOpus = hranaOpus + hranaBarca - canBarca/2;
                    else:
                        hranaOpus = hranaOpus + hranaBarca;

                    if not test_conditie(misMalCurentNou, canMalCurentNou):
                        continue
                    if not test_conditie(misMalOpusNou, canMalOpusNou):
                        continue
                    if barca == 1:  # testul este pentru barca nodului curent (parinte) deci inainte de mutare
                        infoNodNou = (canMalCurentNou, misMalCurentNou, 0)
                    else:
                        infoNodNou = (canMalOpusNou, misMalOpusNou, 1)
                    if not nodCurent.contineInDrum(infoNodNou):
                        listaSuccesori.append(NodParcurgere(infoNodNou, nodCurent))
        print("lista succesori",listaSuccesori)
        return listaSuccesori

    def testeaza_scop(self, nodCurent):
        return nodCurent.info in self.scopuri;

    def __repr__(self):
        sir = ""
        for (k, v) in self.__dict__.items():
            sir += "{} = {}\n".format(k, v)
        return (sir)


def breadth_first(gr):
    global nrSolutiiCautate
    # in coada vom avea doar noduri de tip NodParcurgere (nodurile din arborele de parcurgere)
    c = [NodParcurgere(gr.start, None)]
    continua = True  # variabila pe care o setez la false cand consider ca s-au afisat suficiente solutii
    while (len(c) > 0 and continua):
        # print("Coada actuala: " + str(c))
        # input()
        nodCurent = c.pop(0)

        if gr.testeaza_scop(nodCurent):
            print("Solutie:")
            nodCurent.afisDrum()
            input()
            nrSolutiiCautate -= 1
            if nrSolutiiCautate == 0:
                continua = False
        lSuccesori = gr.genereazaSuccesori(nodCurent)
        c.extend(lSuccesori)


def depth_first(gr):
    # vom simula o stiva prin relatia de parinte a nodului curent
    df(NodParcurgere(gr.noduri.index(gr.start), gr.start, None))


def df(nodCurent):
    global nrSolutiiCautate, continua
    if not continua:
        return
    print("Stiva actuala: " + "->".join(nodCurent.obtineDrum()))
    input()
    if gr.testeaza_scop(nodCurent):
        print("Solutie: ", end="")
        nodCurent.afisDrum()
        nrSolutiiCautate -= 1
        if nrSolutiiCautate == 0:
            continua = False
    lSuccesori = gr.genereazaSuccesori(nodCurent)
    for sc in lSuccesori:
        df(sc)


#############################################


def dfi(nodCurent, adancime):
    global nrSolutiiCautate, continua
    if not continua:
        return
    print("Stiva actuala: " + "->".join(nodCurent.obtineDrum()))
    input()
    if adancime == 1 and gr.testeaza_scop(nodCurent):
        print("Solutie: ", end="")
        nodCurent.afisDrum()
        nrSolutiiCautate -= 1
        if nrSolutiiCautate == 0:
            continua = False
            return
    if adancime > 1:
        lSuccesori = gr.genereazaSuccesori(nodCurent)
        for sc in lSuccesori:
            dfi(sc, adancime - 1)


def depth_first_iterativ(gr):
    for i in range(1, gr.nrNoduri + 1):
        if nrSolutiiCautate == 0:
            break
        print("-----------\nAdancime maxima: ", i)
        dfi(NodParcurgere(gr.noduri.index(gr.start), gr.start, None), i)


gr = Graph("input.txt")
nrSolutiiCautate = 4
breadth_first(gr)
nrSolutiiCautate = 4
continua = True
# depth_first(gr)
nrSolutiiCautate = 4
continua = True
# depth_first_iterativ(gr)
```

**`input.txt`:**

```
N1=4
N2=4
K=2
M=2
Nr=3
MalInitial=vest
MalFinal=est
```

**Actual output:**

```
['N1', '4']
['N2', '4']
['K', '2']
['M', '2']
['Nr', '3']
['MalInitial', 'vest']
['MalFinal', 'est']
['']
lista succesori []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to find out what exactly prevents the `for` loop you seemingly describe to be entered, I inserted a simple `print` statement into the script you gave in line 126:

lines 124 to 127 now read <sup>(keeping original indentation)</sup>:

```py
                minHrana = math.ceil(nodCurent.info[0] - nodCurent.info[1] / 2)
                maxHrana = min(nodCurent.info[5], Graph.M - misBarca - canBarca)
                print(f"minHrana: {minHrana}, maxHrana: {maxHrana}")
                for hrana in range(minHrana, maxHrana):
```

My output is:

```
['N1', '4']
['N2', '4']
['K', '2']
['M', '2']
['Nr', '3']
['MalInitial', 'vest']
['MalFinal', 'est']
['']
minHrana: 2, maxHrana: 1
minHrana: 2, maxHrana: 0
minHrana: 2, maxHrana: 1
minHrana: 2, maxHrana: 0
minHrana: 2, maxHrana: 0
lista succesori []
```

For a [`range(start, stop)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) to be non-empty, it must satisfy the condition `start < stop`.

What we observe, however, whether because of the input or for other reasons, is that the range *is* empty. Consequently, your `for` loop is executed exactly 0 (in words: zero) times.

Comment: Tip you may like.  In Python 3.8+ you can now `print(f'{minHrana=}, {maxHrana=}')` to get that debugging information.

Comment: hard to find an online compiler supporting 3.8+, finally used https://www.python.org/shell/ to see that `x=4; print(f"{x=}")` actually produces `x=4` not a big difference though